# React Native: Disable sound/vibration on push notification

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

I'm sending push notifications from server to clients via google FCM.

In the react-native app I've registered these listeners:

```
this.notificationOpenedListener = firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened(async (notificationOpen) => {

})

this.notificationListener = firebase.notifications().onNotification(async (notification) => {

});
```

the `notification` data contains information if there should be a sound / vibration or not when the notification is received.

However, I can't find any documentation about completely disabling sound/vibration on demand.

How can I achieve this?

UPDATE

I've tried setting sound to an empty string on server side, but there's still sound/vibration on notification.

```
  var message = {
    data: {
      userId: fromUserId,
    },
    notification: {
      title: `My notifcation`,
      body: `Body`,
      sound: "",
    },
  }

  return sendToTopic(topicId, message)
```

Answer (score 0):

When setting your `notification` target, remove `sound` parameter.

```js
const notify = {
     ...message.notification,
     show_in_foreground: true,
     notify_type: message.NotificationType,
     obj_id: message.ObjectId,
     sound: '' // remove this
};
firebase.messaging().createLocalNotification(notify);
```

Comment: Hey i m not using the localnotification :(

Comment: If so, it can be set in the 'Firebase Notification web console'. you can set `sound = disabled` in the advanced option

Comment: you're speaking about the firebase console? I can't find that option. However I'd like to have no sound/vibration only for some notifications while for others i sitll want the sound

Comment: @DanDinu https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support Please refer to this.

Comment: it doesn't have any effect in my case. Check my updated question

Comment: @DanDinu If you remove the sound parameters from the updated question as my answer is, no sound will occur.

Comment: I never had it before and it was still playing/vibrating

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you are setting up your Push notifications but you can tag extra data into the JSON like this:

```
{
  "message":{
    "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "data":{
      "Nick" : "Mario",
      "body" : "great match!",
      "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
    }
  }
}
```

This means you could add a boolean to it to manually play a tone on arrival or not play a tone when the subscription fires, like this:

```
{
  "message":{
    "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "data":{
      "Nick" : "Mario",
      "body" : "great match!",
      "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark",
      "playTone" : "true"
    }
  }
}
```

Then it's the case of having a check in your callback to check the response:

```
this.notificationListener = firebase.notifications().onNotification(async (notification) => {
 if(notification.data.playtone) {
     // Play Tone
     } else {
     // Don't
     }
});
```

In general though push notifications are handled by the OS and not the application, you can hook into it like you have and perform actions on the arrival of a push notification but normally they all arrive in the same "Drop everything and deal with me" style.

Both Android and Apple do support priority but it might not be what you're after:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message

Answer (score 0):

It might be time-consuming and require numerous adjustments to add push notifications to a React Native project. Make sure you properly followed each step because skipping one line could result in hours of debugging.

Follow this link - [Push Notification](https://medium.flatstack.com/migrate-to-api-26-push-notifications-with-custom-sound-vibration-light-14846ebc9e96)